# How to draw the following architecture?

Tags: uml, visio

I am just wondering which program should I use to draw like the following system architecture in http://www.skelta.com/products/Workflow/architecture.aspx

I used visio before but I do not know how to get these shapes!

Comment: I'd say don't bother. I have never heard such a load of useless, meaningless marketing speak in my life! What the hell are they even advertising?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/)?